# UIScrollView contains multiple TableViews with pagingEnabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have an `UIScrollView` that contains 3 `UITableView` and `pagingEnabled = YES`.

Users can pan to the left or right to switch between tables (just like the Notification Center of iOS).

I've handled almost all visual bugs (i can help if anyone needed), but the problem is every table have an `UISearchBar`. Which means  in my controller, I've to create 3 `UITableView`, 3 `UISearchBar` and 3 `UISearchDisplayController`.

That will be one of a hell messy controller.

What the best practice in this case ?

Comment: I would recommend you to take Tableview inside the UICollectionView then there will be no need of taking 3 tableview with 3 UIsearchbar...

Answer (score 0):

It does sound tedious.

Why not create a single UIViewController having a SearchBar and a Tableview. Customize your viewController to be differentiated by tags, add some delegates probably and add it to your UIScrollview? That way, the coding will be structured and clean

I'm just spitballing though.

Comment: do you mean that I should reload data on table when user swipe left and right, right ? I did thing about that but the reason I go with 3 table is I want users are able to long press, pan left-right and the table move along with it. Using one table cannot achieve that AFAIK

Comment: How about this ? A single UIView with all that you want, when you add it you reload the table also?

Answer (score 0):

left or right table will move with your swipe. You have 1 class of your custom UIViewController but different instances.

```
- (SearchResultViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([[LeboncoinAgent shareAgent].searchConditions count] == 0) || (index >= [[LeboncoinAgent shareAgent].searchConditions count])) {
        return nil;
    }


    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    SearchResultViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchResultViewControllerId"];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;
    pageContentViewController.controller = self;

    return pageContentViewController;
}

#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((SearchResultViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;

    _currentPageIndex = index;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```